# How to stop gamemaker object from leaving tracer

Tags: game-maker-studio-2

I have just started to use gamemaker and have made my first very basic game, it's just a circle that moves with the arrow keys.

My problem is that when it moves it leaves behind an image of itself in every space that it occupies. 
All I have is `$motion_set(0, 5);$` as the action.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I am not really familiar with Studio 2 but in 1.4 your code causes my sprite to move across the screen without leaving anything behind. Are you sure there is nothing else in your code. It seems to be re-creating a new sprite either at the old location or  creating a new object at the old location.

You can also you x += (the ammount of pixels you want to move) This works for x and y.

Thanks, Jonathan Greene